# How to call onclick for more href without just triggering the last one - Embedded javascript template

Tags: javascript, onclicklistener, ejs

how to call onclick to trigger function on click?

I defined a couple of elements(href) that need to trigger onclick, in embedded javascript template ... the problem is that function triggered when page load not on click.

```
<%
    function generateEvent( eventName, eventType ){
        //do something
      }

  %>     

    <div class="someClass"> 
       <a href="someUrl"  onclick ="<%{generateEvent('x','y')}; %>;" class="Text" data-value="BI"></a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;


         <a href="someUrl"  onclick ="<%{generateEvent('x','y')}; %>;" class="Text" data-value="FI"></a>&nbsp;|&nbsp;
```

Comment: onclick ="generateEvent('x','y');"

Answer (score 1):

With `ejs` correct syntax is:

```
onclick = "<%= generateEvent('x','y') %>"
```

You need to replace this in your html elements.

OR with es6, you can try simply:

```
onclick = { generateEvent('x','y') }
```

**EDIT**

As per your code in fiddle which is missing `script` tag. I have verfied this to be working with `HTML` and `EJS` both types of files

```
<script>

function generateCustomEvent (eventName, eventType ) { 
   alert("do somethink"+eventName+eventType);
}

</script>

<div class="Class1"> 
    <a href="some_url" onclick = {generateCustomEvent('x','y')} class="CoveoText" data-value="B">hhh</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I have the same behavior, when the page loads then the onclick is executed.
a function is defined within <% %> tags.... some other solution?

<%
function generateEvent( eventName, eventType ){
    //do something
  }
%>

Comment: @Losmi did you tried either of above ? just copy & paste

Comment: @Losmi could you create a fiddle or plunker with minimal reproducible code?

Comment: something like this https://jsfiddle.net/9dpwcq4x/7/ , html is rendered, and it shows everything fine but onclick seems not to work, functions in onclick are immediately executed when loading page

Comment: @Losmi is your file a '.html' or '.ejs' ?

Comment: Can you provide your server.js and view page with minimum required info ?

Answer (score 1):

Figured out :)

```
if we define a function like this
<% 
generateEvent = function (eventName, eventType ){
//do something
} 
%>

//**and call it in HTML**
<div class="Class1"> 
    <a href="some_url" onClick='generateEvent("b1","b")' class="Text" data-value="B">hhh</a>
</div>
 //it will work
```

p.s. tnx @Bilal Siddiqui